# Can a RPI3B+ handle all this?

Tags: sensors, raspberry-pi, sensor-fusion

I am building a robot that needs to accomplish the following tasks:

- Keep track of 4 quadrotor encoders, each 979.62 CPR @ ~ 500RPM, so ~ 8163.5 counts per second
- Read from an [RPlidar A1M8](http://bucket.download.slamtec.com/8d2bb2533f69328982961b14c069983e4acbc01f/robopeak_2d_lidar_brief_en_A1M8.pdf), giving out 8000 samples per second (each sample containing distance, heading, a quality rating of the reading, and a boolean that is true if the device is starting a new revolution).
- Simon Levy's "[Breezy SLAM](https://github.com/simondlevy/BreezySLAM)" algorithm
- Read from a PixyCam's object recognition outputs @ 50Hz
- Read from gyro, 60Hz
- Read from 4 color sensors, 4 ultrasonic sensors, and a TOF sensor, each at around 10Hz
- Fusing above data to get accurate 2D position information, as well as positions of obstacles, within a room of known dimensions (some of the sensors are for other desired pieces of information that I won't go into).  (I'm thinking of going with a Kalman filter - any thoughts on this?)
- Running a task-accomplishing algorithm (possibly a premade Q-learning model)-- for instance, drive towards the nearest obstacle (though my end goal is much more sophisticated than this).

I am wondering if a Raspberry Pi 3B+ could handle all this?  If not what are my options?  Do I need a more powerful computer?  I am thinking I could probably offload the encoder counting to a separate board, and am wondering if there are dedicated ICs for this.

Comment: It is very implementation dependent. If the implementation is bad the first two can probably keep the Pi busy. Is it Multi-threaded? Async? Monolythic or do you have some ipc/rpc? c++ or python? can all encoders go on external interrupts/timers/counters to avoid high frequency polling of GPIOs? Q learning does only expoitation or also exploration? It is a hard question to answer even with all details given.  You could try some arduinos/ESPs/custom boards to do all the GPIO polling related stuff and leave the slam/sensorfusion/Q-learning on the PI

Comment: Yes, I was guessing I would need to I’ve a lot more details to get any specific answer... well do you think I could use a quadrotor encoder buffer to offload the interrupt handling?  That would just leave the RPLidar and slam together with everything else.

Comment: yes, but offload also the low level (PID) controllers to the same device.